# Achieving the same result with HQL in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I would like to implement the following SQL query with Hibernate HQL :

```
select abc_id, count(*) from boa_rep_deed where sync_system = ? And hook_id = ? group by abc_id order by abc_id
```

Now my question is I have the corresponding pojo for this also as shown below..

```
class teedObject{
    private long abcID ;
    private String syncSystem ;
    private String hookId;
    //and consisits other properties and setters and getters
}
```

I have implemented the below criteria..

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("syncSystem", syncSystem));
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("hookId", hookId));
cr.addOrder(Order.asc("abcID"));
cr.add(Projections.groupProperty("abcID")));
cr.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
hytlow = cr.list();
```

Now please advise how can I achieve the same with HQL
Folks please advise

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I guess:

```
select x.abcId, count(x) 
from   teedObject as x 
where  x.syncSystem = :syncSystemParam And x.hookId = :hookIdParam 
group by x.abcId
order by x.abcId
```

HQL is often just like SQL while columns are replaced with properties and tables with classes, corresponding to the mappings.